# Organizer Archive Not validating Iphone APP

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios5, code-signing

I'm running xcode 4.2 on snowleopard.

My Problem

1. When I click "Product -> Archive" in xcode, I am expecting the code signing dialog to pop up like normal and it doesn't
2. When I click the generated archive in the organizer and click "Validate" then "next" to login then "next" with my selected application, it brings up the window that says "Your application is being validated". I had some validation issues that I fixed so the validation seems to be working but it just hangs there. I would expect the code signing dialog to pop up again here and then the next window but just like the last issue, there is no code signing dialog here.

I've tried

1. Rebuilding the project
2. Rebooting my computer
3. Validating a known good build (it's made it past validation before)
4. Reinstalling xcode

I submitted my last version to Apple and they rejected it because it wasn't built with IOS 5.0. I upgraded to xcode 4.2 and haven't seen the code signing dialog pop up since.

**What am I missing here? I think my problem is that the code signing window isn't coming up which it needs to so I can finish validation but I have no idea how to get it to come up.**

Answer (score 1):

Check the projects Build Settings, specifically the "Code Signing Identity" setting.  Make sure you have selected an app store .mobileprovision profile for the Release scheme.

Also open up the Edit Schemes dialog and make sure that the active scheme has an Archive option.  Make sure the Archive option uses the correct Build Configuration ("Release").

Comment: I'm using a valid distribution provisioning profile. I used it for the initial submission that was rejected. I've selected the distribution build configuration and set the signing identity to distribution. None of the helped, but after leaving the window open for 3 hours it randomly went through. The app is in the review status again. Weird but ok. I'll try this again with another app we're releasing soon and get back to this post when the code sign doesn't work again.